# Selecting multiple files to upload based on first selecting (same name, different extensions)

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

as it stands, I have an input field for someone to select a file to upload. It's filtered to only show one extension. That's fine. There's three files with the exact same filename (exception being the extension) that I want to upload

I only want the user to select the .txt file, but I want the other three uploaded as well.

example.txt, example.png, example.htc, example.gif

My current train of thought is to make three more upload fields, set them to display: none and use jquery to get the filename from the visible upload field. Is this a bad idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, browsers won't let this happen for security reasons. Let's say if you had a file with banking information in the same folder an uploaded image. It's a security issue since the user is unaware they have selected the file to be uploaded.

I ended up using plupload, shift + clicking isn't that big of a hassle for an end user.